# Use i18n-abide outside a route

Tags: node.js, internationalization

I know `i18n-abide` add a `req.gettext` but how to handle strings outside a route/controller? 
I mean for example, if I have strings to be translated in a mongoose schema file how can I use the `gettext` method?

Comment: Check out this discussion https://github.com/mozilla/i18n-abide/issues/86